# hook_node_view can't change content

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes

I've read through many questions asking this same thing, but I feel like I'm doing what they are suggesting and it's still not working.

I've created a custom module and enabled it. This is my code:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'teaser' && $node->type == 'article' && count($node->field_video) > 0) {
    kpr($node);

    $markup = sprintf("<video style='width: 502px; height: 282px;' poster='%s'>\n",
        image_style_url('video_thumbnail', $node->field_video[$node->language][0]['thumbnailfile']->uri)
      );

    foreach($node->field_video[$node->language][0]['playablefiles'] as $video_object) {
      $markup .= sprintf("<source src='%s' type='%s' />\n",
          file_create_url($video_object->uri),
          $video_object->filemime
        );
    }

    $markup .= "</video>";

    $node->content['field_video_embed_code'] = array(
      '#markup' => $markup,
      '#weight' => 10,
      '#type'   => 'markup',
    );

    kpr($node);
  }

}
```

When I look at the krumo output, I see my changes to the $node object, however, when it renders the new field I'm adding is not included.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I just realized I'm using Display Suite (it's been awhile since I set this site up) which is overriding which fields are shown and in what order. My guess is that DS is getting my modified content, but not showing the additional field because it isn't listed in my teaser fields? I'm not sure.

Comment: Please provide code of node template file. Maybe you don't output $node->content directly.

Comment: I am using a Zen sub-theme and I haven't overridden Zen's node template, but I'll include it above anyway.

Comment: have you inspected the page source to make sure the <video> tag is definitely missing form the HTML, and not just invisible for some reason?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the raw source in addition the DOM inspector. The video tag is definitely missing.

Comment: What happens if you do a dpm($content) in the template file? Is your field in there? (dpm needs devel module).

Comment: hm, it didn't do anything which was weird. So, I looked around and realized the page is being generated by a View and thought maybe it was producing Fields. I checked the View's configuration and it's set to produce Content:Teaser (not fields). My hook_node_view() is getting called though when I load this page, I've verified that with an error_log(). But I don't know why the dpm() doesn't work. I only have zen and my subtheme in the themes directory and I verified which theme is active, etc.

Comment: Oh, it looks like I'm using Display Suite to override the output of the node! /facepalm

Answer (score 1):

You must declare the field for the DS be able to handle it. In your case:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_extra_fields().
 */
function mymodule_field_extra_fields() {

  $extra['node']['article']['display']['field_video_embed_code'] = array(
    'label' => t('Custom field embed video.'),
    'description' => t('Adds a custom field.'),
    'weight' => 0,
  );
  return $extra;
}
```